# Is there any alternative to flash.error?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

Tomcat 7 does not support the play-framework `#{if flash.success}` tag. I have tested on a few different servers. Is there any other workaround to show a success/error message?

Thanks.

EDIT: I downgraded tomcat to v6. Turns out that I still cannot make the error display. I think its because of how my server is setup. Tomcat resides behind IIS, connected by Boncode AJP connector.

Comment: Can you give more information about why Tomcat 7 "does not support" this tag

Comment: Its mentioned here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/deployment.

Comment: Tomcat7 is not mentioned in the list of supported containers. I tried putting an alert inside the flash.error and tried. I was able to see the alert on Tomcat6. Doesn't work on Tomcat7.

Comment: flash mechanic just store a message in the domain cookie and serve it in the next request. Are you sure you access this page with a redirect ?

Comment: I call flash.error() and the view immediately after. http://pastebin.com/Se7iR594